# Upload Single Image via Input Form and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to upload a single image with Ajax. My problem is NOT how to write the php or the html file. My problem is how to transfer "$_FILE" information which collect by jquery from a form/input/file-type via ajax to php?

actually my script look like this:

**html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pi_form_upload">
     <input style="display:none;" id="pi_upload" type="file"/>
</form>
<a href="" id="upload_link">Submit</a>
```

**js/ajax**

```
//on file change call ajax-function
document.getElementById("pi_upload").onchange = function() {UploadeNewProfilImage();};

function UploadeNewProfilImage() {
   $("#changeProfilImg").css({"display":"none"});

   var formData = new FormData($("#pi_form_upload")[0]);

   $.ajax({
       url: "php/UploadNewProfilImage.php",
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       dataType: "json",
       async: false,
       success: function (data) {
           alert(data)
       },
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false
   });
};
```

until yet i haven't a php file to show because i can't transfer the $_FILE-data. I want to use the upload data such this:

```
//Set Variablen
$ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
$ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.
$ImageTmp       = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$ImageSize      = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
$ImageError     = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
```

I hope someone can help me.

SOLUTION of my problem (from Worldgorger):
give the input a "name"-attribute

Comment: Looking at your code you look close, try adding a "name" field to the <input> and I think that may solve the problem. Since you have $_FILES['myfile'][fieldName], then the name attribute would have a value of "myfile."
Edit: ContentType and processData set to False is good; however, I omitted "async: false" in my code and it works for me. Do you want this to be asynchronous?

Comment: Why are you not directly using the form action attribute to directly send data to the php page?

Comment: @Worldgorger maybe my brain is out of order :) surely you are right. it is the missing name attribute. i stop scripting, better for humanity ;) thx. and no i didnt want async on false.

Comment: @Shikhar because i want to change one image after uploading without reloading the whole page

Comment: @Taeq no worries, don't talk like that! No matter how experienced anyone is we still make mistakes...like when I forget a semicolon or parentheses which makes the whole code invalid O_O